# How to calculate login and logout time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server: how to calculate login and logout time based on below conditions?

1. The same employee may work multiple shifts in the same day. logout and login time difference is more than 5 hours then consider as next shift for that employee.

   Login and logout time more than 5 hours or less or more then consider same shift only for that employee
2. OnFloor time how much time he spend: `sum(login time - logout time)`
3. OffFloor time how much time he spend: `sum(logout time - login time)`

Example: emp: 101 is login time : 2018-02-06 16:03:08.000 and logout time is : 2018-02-06 22:01:40.000 then total time is : 5 hours : 38 min : 32 seconds

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[empstafflogindetails]
(
    [Emp ID] [float] NULL,
    [Area Of Access] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[empstafflogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N' IN', CAST(N'2017-08-02T09:00:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-02T10:30:00.000' AS DateTime)), 
       (1, N' IN', CAST(N'2017-08-03T09:30:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-03T12:30:00.000' AS DateTime)), 
       (1, N' IN', CAST(N'2017-08-03T12:40:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-03T17:10:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' IN', CAST(N'2017-08-03T06:30:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-03T08:30:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' IN', CAST(N'2017-08-05T23:30:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-06T01:55:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' IN', CAST(N'2017-08-06T02:15:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-06T06:10:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' IN', CAST(N'2017-08-02T11:00:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-02T12:00:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' IN', CAST(N'2017-08-02T13:00:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' IN', CAST(N'2017-08-06T14:01:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-06T15:01:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' IN', CAST(N'2017-08-06T15:20:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (1, N' OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-06T20:01:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-05T16:23:49.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' IN', CAST(N'2018-02-05T16:26:01.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' IN', CAST(N'2018-02-05T15:20:07.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-05T16:00:07.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' IN', CAST(N'2018-02-05T16:02:02.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' IN', CAST(N'2018-02-05T22:41:40.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-05T22:56:33.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' IN', CAST(N'2018-02-05T22:58:28.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-05T22:58:32.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' IN', CAST(N'2018-02-05T23:00:28.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-05T21:47:38.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-05T23:28:33.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' IN', CAST(N'2018-02-06T16:03:08.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-06T22:01:40.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' IN', CAST(N'2018-02-06T22:42:15.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-07T01:32:08.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-07T00:33:19.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' IN', CAST(N'2018-02-07T00:33:39.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' IN', CAST(N'2018-02-07T14:57:57.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-07T22:34:51.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' IN', CAST(N'2018-02-07T23:05:13.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-07T23:19:57.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' IN', CAST(N'2018-02-07T23:24:07.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-07T23:31:32.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' IN', CAST(N'2018-02-07T23:34:12.000' AS DateTime)),
       (101, N' OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-07T23:34:36.000' AS DateTime))
GO
```

Based on above data I want output like below :

```
ShiftDate   |ShitStartTime                  |ShiftEndTime               |Total_Time |OnFloor    |OffFloor   |Emp Id
2017-08-02  |2017-08-02 09:00:00.000        |2017-08-02 12:00:00.000    |04:00:00   |02:30:00   |01:30:00   |1
2017-08-03  |2017-08-03 06:30:00.000        |2017-08-03 17:10:00.000    |10:40:00   |09:30:00   |01:10:00   |1
2017-08-05  |2017-08-05 23:30:00.000        |2017-08-06 06:10:00.000    |06:40:00   |06:20:00   |00:20:00   |1
2017-08-06  |2017-08-06 14:01:00.000        |2017-08-06 20:01:00.000    |06:00:00   |05:41:00   |00:19:00   |1
2018-02-05  |2018-02-05 15:20:07.000        |2018-02-05 23:28:33.000    |08:08:26   |07:06:26   |01:02:00   |101
2018-02-06  |2018-02-06 16:03:08.000        |2018-02-07 01:32:08.000    |09:29:00   |08:20:00   |01:09:00   |101
2018-02-07  |2018-02-07 14:57:57.000        |2018-02-07 23:34:36.000    |08:36:39   |07:59:27   |00:37:12   |101
```

I tried like below :

```
select
    cast(ShitStartTime as date) ShiftDate, ShitStartTime, ShiftEndTime
    , concat(right(concat('0', tTime / 60 / 60 % 24), 2), ':', right(concat('0',tTime/ 60 % 60), 2)
    ,':',right(concat('0',tTime % 60), 2)) Total_Time
    ,concat(right(concat('0', onF / 60 / 60 % 24), 2), ':', right(concat('0',onF/ 60 % 60), 2)
    ,':',right(concat('0',onF % 60), 2))OnFloor
    ,
    concat(right(concat('0', offF / 60 / 60 % 24), 2), ':', right(concat('0',offF/ 60 % 60), 2)
    ,':',right(concat('0',offF % 60), 2))OffFloor, [Emp Id]
from (
    select [Emp Id], isnull( min( case when ltrim( rtrim( [Area Of Access]))='in' then Time end  ) ,'1900-01-01')ShitStartTime ,
isnull( max( case when ltrim(rtrim([Area Of Access]))='out'then Time end  ) ,'1900-01-01')ShiftEndTime,
sum(iif(ltrim(rtrim([Area Of Access]))='in', diff, 0)) onF
,sum(iif(ltrim(rtrim([Area Of Access]))='out', diff, 0)) offF
, sum(diff) tTime
 from (
        select *, datediff(SECOND, Time, lead(Time) over (partition by [Emp Id], group_ order by Time)) diff
            
        from (
            select
                *, sum(gr) over (partition by [Emp Id] order by Time rows unbounded preceding) group_
            from (
                select 
                    *, iif(datediff(hh, lag(Time) over (partition by [Emp Id] order by Time), Time) <= 5, 0, 1) gr
                from 
                    empstafflogindetails
                    ) t
        ) t
    ) t
    group by [Emp Id], group_
) t order by [Emp ID],ShiftDate
```

But this query is not returning the expected result. Can you please tell me how to write query to achieve this task in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this query

```
select
    ShiftDate, ShitStartTime, ShiftEndTime
    , Total_Time = right(concat('0', Total_Time / 3600), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', Total_Time % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', Total_Time % 60), 2)
    , OnFloor = right(concat('0', OnFloor / 3600), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', OnFloor % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', OnFloor % 60), 2)
    , OffFloor = right(concat('0', OffFloor / 3600), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', OffFloor % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', OffFloor % 60), 2)
    , [Emp ID]
from (
    select
        [Emp ID], ShiftDate = cast(min(Time) as date)
        , ShitStartTime = min(Time)
        , ShiftEndTime = max(Time)
        , Total_Time = sum(ss)
        , OnFloor = sum(iif(rtrim(ltrim([Area Of Access])) = 'In', ss, 0))
        , OffFloor = sum(iif(rtrim(ltrim([Area Of Access])) = 'Out', ss, 0))
    from (
        select
            *, ss = datediff(ss, Time, lead(Time) over (partition by [Emp ID], grp order by Time))
        from (
            select
                *, grp = sum(diff) over (partition by [Emp ID] order by Time)
            from (
                select
                    *, diff = iif(datediff(mi, lag(Time) over (partition by [Emp ID] order by Time), Time) > 300 and [Area Of Access] = 'IN', 1, 0)
                from
                    [empstafflogindetails]
            ) t
        ) t
    ) t
    group by [Emp ID], grp
) t
```

Output

```
ShiftDate   ShitStartTime             ShiftEndTime              Total_Time    OnFloor     OffFloor  [Emp ID]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-08-02  2017-08-02 09:00:00.000   2017-08-02 13:00:00.000   04:00:00      02:30:00    01:30:00  1
2017-08-03  2017-08-03 06:30:00.000   2017-08-03 17:10:00.000   10:40:00      09:30:00    01:10:00  1
2017-08-05  2017-08-05 23:30:00.000   2017-08-06 06:10:00.000   06:40:00      06:20:00    00:20:00  1
2017-08-06  2017-08-06 14:01:00.000   2017-08-06 20:01:00.000   06:00:00      05:41:00    00:19:00  1
2018-02-05  2018-02-05 15:20:07.000   2018-02-05 23:28:33.000   08:08:26      07:06:26    01:02:00  101
2018-02-06  2018-02-06 16:03:08.000   2018-02-07 01:32:08.000   09:29:00      08:48:05    00:40:55  101
2018-02-07  2018-02-07 14:57:57.000   2018-02-07 23:34:36.000   08:36:39      07:59:27    00:37:12  101
```

Comment: above query is not giving expected result what u have  shown in the output result.

Comment: What result do you get? In your sample data values like `' IN'` and `' OUT'`. I have removed whitespaces

Comment: @balu, Added `rtrim` and `ltrim` to the query

Comment: Hi empid=1 expected shiftstartdate is: 2017-08-02 09:00:00.000 its fine and expected shiftenddate is: 2017-08-02 12:00:00.000 but its showing 2017-08-02 13:00:00.000.expect this remain all records getting correct.can you please tell me where will change in the given script.Thanks

Comment: So you are looking for last `Out` time? Then change `ShiftEndTime = max(Time)` to something like `ShiftEndTime = max(iif(rtrim(ltrim([Area Of Access])) = 'Out', Time, null))`

Comment: Thanks you after add this ShiftEndTime = max(iif(rtrim(ltrim([Area Of Access])) = 'Out', Time, null)),its working good.